# Does this cleanup function in useEffect run even after the component is unmounted?

Tags: reactjs

Right now I am calling an interval function for every 10s. My question is in the useEffect I have a dependency array that has channel id. So when the component unmounts does this clearInterval function gets called?

```
const pollCurrentConversationId = channelID => {
      pollBackendStart({ metadata: { channelID } });
};

const pageFocused = () => {
       if (document.hasFocus()) {
       pollCurrentConversationId(channelID);
     }
     pollingTimerId.current = setInterval(() => {
       if (document.hasFocus()) {
         pollCurrentConversationId(channelID);
       }
     }, 10000);
};

const pageNotFocused = useCallback(() => {
     if (channelID) {
       pollCurrentConversationId(channelID);
     }
     clearInterval(pollingTimerId.current);
   }, [channelID, pollBackendStart]);

useEffect(() => {
     if (channelID) {
       pageFocused();
     }
       return () => {
       clearInterval(pollingTimerId.current);
       };
    }, [currentConversation.id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanup runs when the component is unmounted, regardless of the dependency array. It also runs every time the component rerenders.

Comment: Ok, so when the component is unmounted the cleanup functions run one time right?

Comment: Yes. Even if the interval does exist. This should not be a problem.